# Case is not being auto generated in Opportunity upon field change

Tags: opportunity, case, process-builder, opportunity-lineitem

UPDATE - So the case is being generated, but It's not linked to the opportunity. How do I get it to be linked to the opportunity?

I am creating a Process that is meant to create a new Case in an Opportunity when two fields are the follow: Start Date is not null OR not equal to Target Campaign Start Date. For some reason the case is not being generated within the Opportunity. Please see the steps below:

1. Choose Object and Specify When to Start the Process
   [image]
2. Define Criteria for this Action Group
   [image]
3. Create a Record
   [image]

Please help.

Comment: You are relating the case to the account through the oppty, When you go to the account do you see the case in account related list? If you want to see the case as a related list under oppty then you will have to create an association between case and oppty. Do you have this case <-> oppty connection built?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a master detail relationship between the opportunity and case objects. Setup -> opportunity Fields ->  new -> master detail field

I believe you should put the field on the opportunity, you'll have to play with it. You can also create the connection using a lookup.